# React Native Component dismounts unexpectedly

Tags: react-native, react-component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Alert} from 'react-native';
import {  Text } from 'native-base';



export default class BlankScreen extends Component {
  
     componentWillUnmount() {
         Alert.alert("UnMounted"); 
      } 
  render(){
      return(
          <Text>Hello</Text>
      )
  }

}
```

I am working on an app which have almost 20 to 25 component but one of these components,when mounts for the first time, dismounts unexpectedly with the warning shown that " Can't Perform a React Native State update on an unmounted component".

Any one who have encountered the same scenario can give a solution to this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to post some code. Also try to google your error, you'll find some helpful things

Comment: yeah i have uploaded a code snippet..